# Selecting data from a table in mathematica

Tags: select, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to write a function that will take select the first element in the table that satisfies a criteria.  For example, if I am given the following table with times in the first column and number of people infected with a disease in the second, I want to write an argument that will return the time where at least 100 people are infected.

```
0   1
1   2
2   4
3   8
4   15
5   29
6   50
7   88
8   130
9   157
10  180
11  191
12  196
13  199
14  200
```

So from this table, I want the arguemnt to tell me that at 8 seconds, at least 100 people were infected.  I tried using SELECT to do this, but I'm not sure how to use SELECT with a table of 2 columns and have it return a value in the first column based on criteria from the second column.

Comment: is this really a Mathematica question?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative that uses replacement rules is

```
ImportString["0 1 1 2 2 4 3 8 4 15 5 29 6 50 7 88 8 130 9 157 10 180 11 191 12 196 13 199 14 200", "Table"];
Partition[Flatten[%], 2]
% /. {___, x : {_, _?(# >= 100 &)}, ___} :> x
```

The algorithm with which Mathematica searches for patterns ensures that this will return the first such case.  If you want all cases then you can use ReplaceList.
I suggest you read the tutorial on [Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Introduction-Patterns.html) and [Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/RulesAndPatterns.html).

---

Edit: `ImportString` works on the newly formatted data as well - but you no longer need to use `Partition`.

Comment: +1, clever use of patterns.  Since, she wants the value in the first column only, I'd change your pattern to `{___, {x_, _?(# >= 100 &)}, ___}`.  Otherwise, no change.

Comment: +1 because replacement rules are usually much faster than `Cases`, `Select`, or `Position`.

Comment: @Timo pattern matching is actually much slower than Cases and Select as given by Joshua, in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a simple NestWhile

```
data = {{0,1},{1,2},{2,4},{3,8},{4,15},{5,29},{6,50},{7,88},{8,130},{9,157},{10,180},
 {11,191},{12,196},{13,199},{14,200}};
NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, data[[#, 2]] < 100 &] - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few different ways to do this, assuming I've interpreted your data correctly...

```
In[3]:= data = {{0,1},{1,2},{2,4},{3,8},{4,15},{5,29},{6,50},{7,88},{8,130},{9,157},{10,180},{11,191},{12,196},{13,199},{14,200}};

In[8]:= Cases[data, {_, _?(#>=100&)}, 1, 1][[1, 1]]
Out[8]= 8

In[9]:= Select[data, #[[2]]>=100&, 1][[1, 1]]
Out[9]= 8
```

I suggest you read up on Part[] to understand this better.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a faster way than what has already been given, but first, Joshua's `Cases` method can be made a little faster by using `/;` rather than `&` for the test.

This is the solution I propose (edit: adding white space for clarity, since the double brackets do not format here):

```
dat[[
  Position[
    dat[[All, 2]],
    x_ /; x >= 100,
    1, 1
  ][[1, 1]],
  1
]]
```

Here are timings for the various methods offered.  Please note that the `/.` method is only being run once, while the others are being run `loops` times.  Therefore, in this first test it is 100x slower than the `Position` method.  Also, the `NestWhile` method is only returning an index, rather than an actual first column element.

```
In[]:= 
dat = {Range[5000], Sort@RandomInteger[1*^6, 5000]} // Transpose;
lim = 300000; loops = 100;
dat /. {___, {x_, _?(# >= lim &)}, ___} :> x; // Timing
Do[  Cases[dat, {_, _?(# >= lim &)}, 1, 1][[1, 1]]  , {loops}] // Timing
Do[  Cases[dat, {_, y_ /; y >= lim}, 1, 1][[1, 1]]  , {loops}] // Timing
Do[  Select[dat, #[[2]] >= lim &, 1][[1, 1]]  , {loops}] // Timing
Do[  NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, dat[[#, 2]] < lim &]  , {loops}] // Timing
Do[  dat[[Position[dat[[All, 2]], x_ /; x >= lim, 1, 1][[1, 1]], 1]]  , {loops}] // Timing

Out[]= {0.125, Null}

Out[]= {0.438, Null}

Out[]= {0.406, Null}

Out[]= {0.469, Null}

Out[]= {0.281, Null}

Out[]= {0.125, Null}
```

With a longer table (I leave out the slow method):

```
In[]:= 
dat = {Range[35000], Sort@RandomInteger[1*^6, 35000]} // Transpose;
lim = 300000; loops = 25;
Do[  Cases[dat, {_, _?(# >= lim &)}, 1, 1][[1, 1]]  , {loops}] // Timing
Do[  Cases[dat, {_, y_ /; y >= lim}, 1, 1][[1, 1]]  , {loops}] // Timing
Do[  Select[dat, #[[2]] >= lim &, 1][[1, 1]]  , {loops}] // Timing
Do[  NestWhile[# + 1 &, 1, dat[[#, 2]] < lim &]  , {loops}] // Timing
Do[  dat[[Position[dat[[All, 2]], x_ /; x >= lim, 1, 1][[1, 1]], 1]]  , {loops}] // Timing

Out[]= {0.734, Null}

Out[]= {0.641, Null}

Out[]= {0.734, Null}

Out[]= {0.5, Null}

Out[]= {0.266, Null}
```

Finally, confirmation of agreement:

```
In[]:= SameQ[
         Select[dat, #[[2]] >= lim &, 1][[1, 1]],
         dat[[Position[dat[[All, 2]], x_ /; x >= lim, 1, 1][[1, 1]], 1]]
       ]

Out[]= True
```