# Subscripted variables

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there any way to force Mathematica to treat subscripted variables independently of their unsubscripted counterparts? More specifically. Say, I have the following definitions:

```
Subscript[b, 1] = {{1, 2}}
Subscript[b, 2] = {{3, 4}}
b = Join[Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[b, 2]]
```

Now when I use

```
Subscript[b, 1]
```

Mathematica will substitute it with

```
Subscript[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}},1]
```

when I want these to be three independent values, so changing b will not affect Subscript[b, ..]. Is it possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In an answer to a previous SO question, [Mathematica Notation and syntax mods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439660/mathematica-notation-and-syntax-mods/5442152#5442152), [telefunkenvf14](https://stackoverflow.com/users/667867/telefunkenvf14) mentioned that he was

> hoping to use Notations to force MMA
>   to treat subscripted variables as a symbol

which is essentially what this question is about.

[WReach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211232/wreach) pointed out that the [Notation package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html) can do this quite simply using `Symbolize`

```
Needs["Notation`"];
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]
```

Where (as in Daniel's answer) don't worry too much about the `Box` structure above as you can use the `Notation` palette to enter this stuff in more simply.

Check that it all works as wanted:

```
In[3]:= Subscript[a, b]//Head
        a = 1
        Subscript[a, b]

Out[3]= Symbol
Out[4]= 1
Out[5]= Subscript[a, b]
```

and

```
In[6]:= Subscript[b, 1] = {{1, 2}}
        Subscript[b, 2] = {{3, 4}}
        b = Join[Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[b, 2]]
Out[6]= {{1, 2}}
Out[7]= {{3, 4}}
Out[8]= {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

---

**Note:** all of the above code has been [copied as Input Text](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ClipboardOperations.html), so the typeset `SubscriptBox`s have been converted to the input form `Subscript`s. However, the `Symbolize` works at the box level, so the tests need to be converted back to their 2d forms. To do this, select the code (or cells) and [convert it to standard form](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ChangeTheFormOfInputAndOutput.html) by using the `Cell` menu or the [shortcut](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html) `Ctrl-Shift-N`. The notebook with all the above code should look like
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the `Notation` package (see [Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481216/subscripted-variables/5481422#5481422) and [my](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481216/subscripted-variables/5481726#5481726) answers) but want to copy the behaviour of `Symbolize`, then it gets a little tricky.

I had a go at doing this after I reading this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5439660/mathematica-notation-and-syntax-mods/5442152#5442152) but ran into troubles and gave up. I'll put the code here as community wiki so other people can try to finish it!

First you want to intercept an inputted subscript box structure and make it be interpreted as a "unique" symbol. The following code

```
MakeExpression[SubscriptBox[x_String, i_String], form_] := 
 With[{name = StringJoin[{"$sUbsCript$", x, "$SPLIT$", i}]}, 
  Hold[Symbol[name]]]
```

makes an inputted `x_i` become a symbol named `"$sUbsCript$x$SPLIT$i"`. Not a guaranteed unique symbol name... but it would a fairly unusual one! 
Notes:
1) that this code will not pick up subscripts written in `FullForm`.
2) this definition only fires off if both parts of the subscript are "simple" - no spaces, brackets, operators, etc...

Next, because this symbol name is so ugly, here's an optional something to make it nicer when it's asked for (this probably should be changed)

```
Protect[$inSymbolName];
Unprotect[SymbolName];
SymbolName[symb_Symbol] := 
 Block[{$inSymbolName = True, result, s},
   result = If[StringMatchQ[s = SymbolName[symb], "$sUbsCript$" ~~ __],
     StringJoin@StringSplit[StringDrop[s, 11], "$SPLIT$"],
     s]] /; ! TrueQ[$inSymbolName]
Protect[SymbolName];
```

Finally, we want this subscript symbol to print out nicely. Normally we'd do this using a `MakeBoxes` definition -- but we can't in this case because `Symbol` has the attribute `Locked`    :(
Instead, we'll hack in a `$PrePrint` to find these crazily named symbols and write them back as subscripts:

```
$PrePrint = (# /. s_Symbol :> 
  Block[{$inSymbolName = True}, 
    If[StringMatchQ[SymbolName[s], "$sUbsCript$" ~~ __], 
       Subscript@@StringSplit[StringDrop[SymbolName[s], 11], "$SPLIT$"], s]]
   )&;
```

Finally the place where all of this falls down is if you try to assign something to a subscripted symbol. I haven't tried working around this yet!

Some tests - note that you'll have to convert the `Subscript`s to actual boxes for the code to work. Do this by converting to StandardForm: Ctrl-Shift-N.

```
symbs = {x, yy, Subscript[a, 3], Subscript[long, name]};

In[10]:= Head/@symbs
Out[10]= {Symbol, Symbol, Symbol, Symbol}

In[11]:= SymbolName/@symbs
Out[11]= {x, yy, a3, longname}

In[12]:= Block[{$inSymbolName=True},SymbolName/@symbs]
Out[12]= {x, yy, $sUbsCript$a$SPLIT$3, $sUbsCript$long$SPLIT$name}

In[13]:= f[x_Symbol] := Characters[SymbolName[x]]
In[14]:= {f["acb"], f[abc], f[Subscript[xx, 2]]}
Out[14]= {f["acb"], {"a", "b", "c"}, {"x", "x", "2"}}
```

It doesn't work with `Set` or `SetDelayed` if they generate `OwnValues` and it doesn't work with  `Information`

```
In[15]:= Subscript[x, y] = 5
         ??Subscript[x, y]
During evaluation of In[4]:= Set::write: Tag Symbol in Symbol[$sUbsCript$x$SPLIT$y] is Protected. >>
Out[15]= 5
During evaluation of In[4]:= Information::nomatch: No symbol matching Symbol["$sUbsCript$x$SPLIT$y"] found. >>
```

It does work with definitions that produce `DownValues`

```
In[17]:= Subscript[x, z][z_]:=z^2
In[18]:= Subscript[x, z][2]
Out[18]= 4

In[19]:= ?Subscript[x, z]
Information::nomatch: No symbol matching Symbol["$sUbsCript$x$SPLIT$z"] found. >>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code I used to use to do this. It should work for you too:

```
SubscriptToProxySymbol[_] = Null;
MakeExpression[SubscriptBox[a_, b_], StandardForm] := 
 Module[{proxy, boxes = SubscriptBox[a, b]}, 
  proxy = SubscriptToProxySymbol[boxes];
  If[proxy === Null, proxy = ToString[Unique[ProxySymbol]];
   SubscriptToProxySymbol[boxes] = proxy;
   With[{n = Symbol[proxy]}, MakeBoxes[n, StandardForm] := boxes];];
  MakeExpression[RowBox[{proxy}], StandardForm]]
```

With this, definitions like

```
f[Subscript[a, b] : _] := Sin[Subscript[a, b]]
```

are internally stored like this:

```
In[11]:= InputForm@DownValues[f]

Out[11]//InputForm=
{HoldPattern[f[ProxySymbol$99_]] :> Sin[ProxySymbol$99]}
```

But they display as subscripts.

From a quick look I think this may be what Simon was aiming for.

If your application allows it, you may wish to consider adopting Mathematica-like naming conventions such as FullyDescriptiveCamelCase variable names instead of subscripted variables. It will make your code more portable in the end, and it does become second nature eventually.

Comment: Hi Andrew - Just saw this. It works nicely and is much more sane than my approach. +1

Answer (score 1):

The symbol is `b`, and not `Subscript[b, _]`.

When you define:

```
Subscript[b, 1] = {{1, 2}}
```

is like defining a downvalue for any function f. Like doing:

```
f[b, 2] = {{1, 2}}
```

So, what you are doing is

```
f[b, 1] = {{1, 2}} 
f[b, 2] = {{3, 4}} 
b = Join[f[b, 1], f[b, 2]]
```

Which of course assigns a value to the symbol b.

and now

```
f[b, 1]
->f[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 1]
```

As expected.

So, I guess the short answer is no. At least not in a straightforward way.

**Edit**

While the above is true (I believe), I wasn't aware that the Notation package has a way to circumvent the default behavior. Other answers contain the details.

Comment: Of course, I wonder what internal magic the Notation package actually uses to achieve what it does? For example what does `Symbolize` actually do?

Comment: @Simon ha! I posted and then deleted a similar comment on your answer. That kind of things makes me shudder :)

Comment: It wouldn't be so bad - except that `Symbol` is `Locked` - which prevents you from giving it extra `MakeBoxes` definitions. See the [Community Wiki "answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481216/subscripted-variables/5481897#5481897) I posted below.

Comment: @Simon I think your answer is a very nice one, but I doubt about the robustness of the whole thing. When you want a calc done Mma is great, but the environment per se looks fragile, and the debug process (hard on its own) is usually more difficult each time you add a level of abstraction/redefinition.

Comment: The answer has serious problems - I only put it up so that other people can procrastinate by fixing it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Could use Notation from the package of same name.

Don't mind the code below, you don't figure out that RowBox structure. Just use the palette template and type Subscript[b,j_] into the left side, and, say, bb[j_], into the right. So the "actual"variables are now bb[1] etc., and you can assign safely to b.

```
Needs["Notation`"]

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
  RowBox[{"Subscript", "[", 
   RowBox[{"b", ",", "j_"}], "]"}]] \[DoubleLongRightArrow] 
   ParsedBoxWrapper[
  RowBox[{"bb", "[", "j_", "]"}]]]

Subscript[b, 1] = {{1, 2}}
Subscript[b, 2] = {{3, 4}}
b = Join[Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[b, 2]]
```

Out[3]= {{1, 2}}

Out[4]= {{3, 4}}

Out[5]= {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}

```
Subscript[b, 1]
```

Out[6]= {{1, 2}}

You'll probably get more accurate replies, this is the first I ever mucked with the Notation package.

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: @Daniel As it should be obvious from my answer, I never did. :)

Comment: Hi Daniel: The Notation package has a command called `Symbolize` that is designed to do what Max wanted. The full `Notation` command is not needed.

Comment: Potential issue with custom notation is that parsing mechanism for .nb and .m files is different. It definitely causes a problem for InfixNotation (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/wABDm0h1EHg/CHHrGkdfbcIJ), not sure about Symbolize

Comment: @Daniel I'm puzzled by your answer. If you input `Subscript[b,1]` you will indeed get `{{1,2}}` as output.  But if you enter the same thing formatted as a subscript, ie. b+Control[-], you will obtain a nicely rendered result of `Subscript[{{1,2},{3,4}},1]` in return.

Comment: @David: Try using the command `Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[\(b\_j_\)] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] ParsedBoxWrapper[\(bb[j_]\)]]`.

Comment: @David It works for me, as long as you don't mix Subscript[b,1] and b_1 (_ indicating subscripting). So, b_1 = {{1, 2}}; b_2 = {{3, 4}}
b = Join[b_1, b_2] works, but  b_1 = {{1, 2}}; b_2 = {{3, 4}}
b = Join[Subscript[b, 1], Subscript[b, 2]] (on a clean kernel) yields b[1, 2]

Comment: @Simon Thanks, it works.  Now I'll try to figure out why.  I'll be reflecting on your code and Sjoerd's.

Answer (score 0):

I studied the thread on subscripted variables in detail by pasting the various replies into a Mathematica notebook (and tried it with version 7 and 8). However, what I found out that in some cases the explicit representation of subscripted variables as `Subscript[a,b]` does not give the correct answer as contained in these answers. However, when I used explicitly the 2d notation for subscript ( a_b ) the answer was as expected. Could it be that when pasting subscripted symbols into an email they are represented as 
`Subscript[a,b]`. (Of course, I should add that for each individual contributions I started Mathematica fresh - after using `Quit[ ]` ).

Comment: Hi Robert, welcome to Stack Overflow. Posting a new answer is not really the place for such a comment, but since you don't have enough [reputation to comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment), I guess there's not much else you could do to raise this valid point. Mathematica automatically converts the subscript boxes to full form when copying as input text, I think that everyone automatically converted the full form back to boxes when testing and no-one thought of mentioning this fact. I'll update my answer to reflect this concern.