# Having a parameter with subscript and superscript

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to define an object/symbol in mathematica which will have several parameters, for example, something like: `S=(1-t)({b_i}^x,{b_i}^y)+t({b_{i+1}}^x,{b_{i+1}}^y)` (sort of LaTeX notation). In the example I'm trying to describe the line segment connecting two points `b_i` and `b_{i+1}`.

**How can I define such an object in `mathematica`?**

I found the following two questions:

- [Mathematica Notation and syntax mods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5439660/671013)
- [Subscripted variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5481216/671013)

But I'm not sure that I am using them correctly. What I have done is the following. First I invoked:

```
Needs["Notation`"];

Symbolize[
ParsedBoxWrapper[
SubscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"]]]

Symbolize[
ParsedBoxWrapper[
SuperscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[Placeholder]"]]]
```

Then, I actually defined the object:

```
(1 - t) {Subscript[b, i]^x, Subscript[b, i]^y} + 
 t {Subscript[b, i + 1]^x, Subscript[b, i + 1]^y}
```

**Is this the right way to do what I want?**

Comment: I also have trouble understanding this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you want. The 'object' you are talking about

```
(1 - t) {Subscript[b, i]^x, Subscript[b, i]^y} + 
 t {Subscript[b, i + 1]^x, Subscript[b, i + 1]^y}
```

isn't really a single entity, but the sum of two lists each consisting of two components. So, I assume that you really want to define `Subscript[b, i]^x` as a symbol.

You can do this with `Symbolize` from the `Notation` package. It's absolutely crucial, though, that you use the template generated when you press the Symbolize button on the Notation palette (you get this upon running `` << Notation` ``). Then enter your compound variable. I'll be assuming the superscript x and y are fixed symbols and the subscript `i`s are variable:

[image]

---

**One more thing:**

It might not be a good idea to use `Subscript[b, i]^y` as you'd lose the ability to raise subscripted variables to the power x and y (a minor loss, but still). Instead you might want to use `Subsuperscript[b,i,y]`. Please note that the sentence in the 'More information' part of the `Subsuperscript` documentation page **seems to be patently wrong**. It says:

> To enter a subsuperscript in a notebook, use either Ctrl+_ to begin a
>   regular subscript or Ctrl+^ to begin a regular superscript. After
>   typing the first script, use Ctrl+% to move to the opposite script
>   position. Ctrl+Space moves out of the subscript or superscript
>   position.

If you do a `FullForm` on the resulting object you'll see you have made a `Subscript[b, i]^y` instead. To get the symbol for pasting in the Symbolize template I see no other solution than typing `Subsuperscript[b, i_, y]`, evaluating, and copying the result to the template.

Comment: @Simon I'm sorry, I don't quite follow

Comment: The documentation is not patently wrong, it just doesn't tell the whole story.
Following the key-strokes in the documentation will produce a `Subsuperscriptbox` which is what will be seen by the Notation package. However, Mma by default interprets that as a `Power[Subscript[..]]`, which is normally what you want. When you create use `Subsuperscript` in the input, Mma protects it from the standard interpretation by creating a `InterpretationBox[SubsuperscriptBox[...], Subsuperscript[...],  Editable->False]]`, and that `Editable->False` bit is annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Sjoerd's answer: Since you say the symbol `S` takes various parameters, I think you might want to explore the[`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html) method to define a function with parameters. Assumuing that you do want `S` to be vector-valued with two points, then something like the following would define `S` in the way you want it.

```
S[x_,y_,t_,i_]:= (1-t) * {b[i]^x,b[i]^y} + t * {(b[i+1])^x,(b[i+1])^y}
```

The question then is whether you really need the subscripting. Sjoerd's answer shows how this is done using the Notation package, but you should consider whether this additional complication is necessary to your analysis.

**EDIT in response to rcollyer's very helpful comment**
You can use [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Format.html) to define a [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TraditionalForm.html) representations for a custom function. This is similar to defining [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpValues.html), but relates to the representation rather than the re-writing rules.

Something like the following should work:

```
Format[S[x_,y_,t_,i_],TraditionalForm] := 
  (1 - t) {Subscript[b, i]^x, Subscript[b, i]^y} +         
  t {Subscript[b, i + 1]^x, Subscript[b, i + 1]^y}
```

Comment: You're looking for [`Format`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Format.html).