# Plot using With versus Plot using Block (Mathematica)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to describe an issue I have been having with `Plot` using `With` to keep defined parameters 'local'. I am not necessarily asking for a fix: the problem I have is one of understanding.

Sometimes I use a construction such as the following to obtain a Plot:

**Method 1**

```
plot1 = With[{vmax = 10, km = 10}, 
  Plot[Evaluate@((vmax x)/(km + x)), {x, 0, 100}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]
```

I like this method, and it is reasonably clear even to non-*Mathematica* users exactly what is going on.

When the equations to be plotted become more complex, I like to define them external to the plot (using SetDelayed).  For example:

```
f[x_] := (vmax x)/(km + x)
```

However, the following *does not work*

**Method 2**

```
plot2 = With[{vmax = 10, km = 10}, 
  Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 100}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]
```

I have always naively thought that it should. However, based on the Help statement that

> Plot treats the variable x as local,
>   effectively using Block

I have used various workarounds, mostly something like the following

**Method 3**

```
plot3 = Plot[With[{vmax = 10, km = 10}, Evaluate@f[x]], {x, 0, 100}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

This one seems very awkward, and usually requires further explanation even to *Mathematica* users.

*Plot outputs*

[image]

However, recently I found out by chance that substituting `Block` for `With` in Method 2 works exactly as expected.

I can, for example, do something like the following (which to me seems a very versatile approach):

```
plot4 = Block[{vmax = {10, 10, 10}, km = { 10, 100, 1000}}, 
  Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 100}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]]
```

giving

[image]

My questiions are as follows.  What is the explanation for the difference in behaviour with `With` in Method 1 and 2?  Should I have expected Method 2 not to work?  Furthermore, what is the explanation for the difference in behaviour with `Block` and `With` in Method 2?  Should I have been able to predict that `Block` would work?

Funnily enough many workarounds have been suggested to me by those more experienced than I, but nobody suggested using `Block`.

Finally, I need to keep `vmax` and `km` local.(They have been defined algebraically elsewhere)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Your question is not so much about `Plot` as it is about how the scoping constructs work. The main confusion here is due to the differences between lexical and dynamic scoping. And the main culprit is this definition:

```
f[x_] := (vmax x)/(km + x)
```

The problem with it is that it makes `f` implicitly depend on the global symbols (variables) `vmax` and `km`. I am very much against this sort of constructs since they lead to infinite confusion. Now, what happens can be illustrated with the following example:

```
In[55]:= With[{vmax =1, km = 2},f[x]]

Out[55]= (vmax x)/(km+x)
```

To understand why this happens, one must understand what the *lexical* scoping means. We know that `With` has a `HoldAll` attribute. The way it works is that it looks are what is *literally* inside it, and substitutes variables found *literally* in the body with their values from the declaration list. This happens during the variable-binding stage, and only then it lets the body to evaluate. From this, it is clear that the following will work:

```
In[56]:= With[{vmax =1, km = 2},Evaluate[f[x]]]

Out[56]= x/(2+x)
```

This worked because `Evaluate` overrides the "part" of `HoldAll` attribute of `With`, forcing  the body to evaluate before anything else (variable binding, and subsequent body evaluation). Therefore, it would be completely equivalent to use just `With[{vmax = 1, km = 2}, (vmax x)/(km + x)]` above, as you can see with `Trace`. The next part of the puzzle is why

```
With[{vmax = 10, km = 10}, Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 100}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]
```

does not work. This is because this time we *do not* evaluate the body first. The presence of `Evaluate` affects only `f[x]` inside `Plot`, but not the evaluation of `Plot` itself inside `With`. This is illustrated by

```
In[59]:= With[{vmax = 10, km = 10}, q[Evaluate@f[x]]]

Out[59]= q[(vmax x)/(km + x)]
```

Moreover, we do not want `Plot` to evaluate first, since then the values of `vmax` and `km` will not be defined. However, all that `With` sees is `f[x]`, and since the parameters `vmax` and `km` are not *literally* present in there (lexical scoping, remember), no substitution will be made. Should we use `Block` here, and things will work, because `Block` uses dynamic scoping, meaning that it redefines values in time (part of the execution stack if you wish), rather than in place. Therefore, using `Block[{a =1, b =2}, ff[x]]` where `ff` implicitly depends on `a` and `b` is (roughly) equivalent to `a=1;b=2;ff[x]` (with the difference that `a` and `b` resume their global values after the `Block` scope is left). So,

```
In[60]:= Block[{vmax = 10, km = 10}, q[Evaluate@f[x]]]

Out[60]= q[(10 x)/(10 + x)]
```

To make the `With` version work, you'd have to inject the expression for `f[x]` (r.h.s), for example like so:

```
In[63]:= Unevaluated[With[{vmax = 10, km = 10}, q[f[x]]]] /. DownValues[f]

Out[63]= q[(10 x)/(10 + x)]
```

Note that this won't work:

```
In[62]:= With[{fx = f[x]}, With[{vmax = 10, km = 10},  q[fx]]]

Out[62]= q[(vmax x)/(km + x)]
```

But the reason here is quite subtle: while outer `With` evaluates before the inner one, it spots the variable name conflicts and renames its variables. Rules are much more disruptive, they don't respect inner scoping constructs.

*EDIT*

If one insists on nested `With`-s, here is how one can fool the name conflict resolution mechanism of `With` and make it work:

```
In[69]:= With[{fx = f[x]}, With @@ Hold[{vmax = 10, km = 10}, q[fx]]]

Out[69]= q[(10 x)/(10 + x)]
```

Since outer `With` can no longer detect the presence of inner `With` (using `Apply[With,Hold[...]]` makes the inner `With` effectively dynamically generated), it does not make any renamings, and then it works. This is a general trick to fool lexical scoping name resolution mechanism when you don't want renaming, although the necessity to use it usually indicates a bad design.

*END EDIT*

But I digressed. To summarize, making your second method work is quite hard and requires really weird constructs like

```
Unevaluated[ With[{vmax = 10, km = 10}, Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 100},
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]] /.  DownValues[f]
```

or

```
With[{fx = f[x]}, 
   With @@ Hold[{vmax = 10, km = 10}, 
       Plot[Evaluate@fx, {x, 0, 100}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]]
```

Once again: all this is because `With` must "see" the variables explicitly in the code, to make replacements. In contrast, `Block` does not need that, it replaces values dynamically at the moment of evaluation, based on their modified global values, as if you made assignments, this is why it works.

Now, the real culprit is your definition of `f`. You could have avoided all these troubles should you have defined your `f` with explicit parameter-passing:

```
ff[x_, vmax_, km_] := (vmax x)/(km + x)
```

Now, this works out of the box:

```
With[{vmax = 10, km = 10}, 
   Plot[Evaluate@ff[x, vmax, km], {x, 0, 100}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]
```

because the parameters are explicitly present in the function call signature, and so are visible to `With`.

To summarize: what you observed is a consequence of the interplay between lexical and dynamic scoping. Lexical scoping constructs must "see" their variables explicitly in the code at the variable-binding stage (before evaluation), or they won't be effective. Dynamic scoping effectively modifies *values* of symbols, and is in this sense less demanding (the price you pay is that the code using lots of dynamic scoping is harder to understand, since it mixes state and behavior). The main reason for trouble is the function definition that makes implicit dependencies on global symbols (that are not in the formal parameter list of the function). It is best to avoid such constructs. It is still possible to make things work, but this is considerably more complicated (as was demonstrated above), and, at least for the case at hand, for no good reason.

Comment: @Leonid.  That is a great explanation. A lot of things have become clearer. Your examples have explained a lot, and your advise on function definition has simplified things quite a bit. Many, many thanks

Comment: @Leonid. I was really delighted when I saw it was you who had answered my question :-)

Comment: @TomD, @David Thanks, it was my pleasure! Besides, I think that such discussion was needed here on SO, since this sort of questions pop up often and also are very important - scoping is one of the foundations of the language. @TomD Thanks for the accept!

Comment: @LeonidShifrin great answer. do you think we really need the `Evaluate` in `Unevaluated[ With[{vmax = 10, km = 10}, Plot[Evaluate@f[x], {x, 0, 100},
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]] /.  DownValues[f]` since we are already injecting the `DownValues` of f in the unevaluated expression. It can run without it.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong but does using `Hold` in the code immediately below the one posted above result in a non-standard evaluation. My thinking is that the external `With` does not get the chance to see the internal `With` which results in the replacement of `fx` inside `Hold` (which is also evaluated because of `Evaluate[fx]`). It is only at the end that the internal `With` gets applied as the Head of the expression and since the variables `vmax` and `km` are already visible by now, the replacements of `vmax` and `km` with their explicit values take place. Am i correct?

Comment: @AliHashmi Re: `Evaluate` - may be we don't need it there, you may be right. Re: non-standard evaluation - the external `With` actually *can* see all its internal code, including inner `With` - because `With` itself uses non-standard evaluation. `Hold` is needed to fool the external `With`, so that it does not detect internal `With` and does not try to rename variables.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thank you very much. now i understand what is going on. The external `With` can see all the internals and replaces `fx` literally. The `Hold` prevents the internal `With` from being applied first. This enables `km` and `val` to assume values after `fx` has been literally replaced. Pretty neat trick :)

Answer (score 2):

Just two comments:

- using Block, you don't need to use Evaluate. That is, Block[{vmax = 10, km = 2}, Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 100}] will work.
- Another way to do this is to define substitution rules:
  rule = {vmax -> 10, km -> 10}; Plot[f[x] /. rule, {x, 0, 100}]
  The advantage is that you can re-use the rule in other statements.
  In addition, you can define multiple substition rules for different cases: rule1 = {vmax -> 10, km -> 10}, rule2 = {vmax -> 2,  km -> 2}