# Store unevaluted function in list mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Example:

```
list:={ Plus[1,1], Times[2,3] }
```

When looking at `list`, I get

```
{2,6}
```

I want to keep them unevaluated (as above) so that `list` returns

```
{ Plus[1,1], Times[2,3] }
```

Later I want to evaluate the functions in list sequence to get

```
{2,6}
```

The number of unevaluated functions in `list` is not known beforehand. Besides `Plus`, user defined functions like `f[x_]` may be stored in `list`

I hope the example is clear.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way is to store them in `Hold`, not `List`, like so:

```
In[255]:= f[x_] := x^2;
lh = Hold[Plus[1, 1], Times[2, 3], f[2]]

Out[256]= Hold[1 + 1, 2 3, f[2]]
```

In this way, you have full control over them. At some point, you may call `ReleaseHold` to evaluate them:

```
In[258]:= ReleaseHold@lh

Out[258]= Sequence[2, 6, 4]
```

If you want the results in a list rather than `Sequence`, you may use just `List@@lh` instead. If you need to evaluate a specific one, simply use `Part` to extract it:

```
In[261]:= lh[[2]]

Out[261]= 6
```

If you insist on your construction, here is a way:

```
In[263]:= l:={Plus[1,1],Times[2,3],f[2]};
Hold[l]/.OwnValues[l]

Out[264]= Hold[{1+1,2 3,f[2]}]
```

**EDIT**

In case you have some functions/symbols with `UpValues` which can evaluate even inside `Hold`, you may want to use `HoldComplete` in place of `Hold`.

**EDIT2**

As pointed by @Mr.Wizard in another answer, sometimes you may find it more convenient to have `Hold` wrapped around individual items in your sequence. My comment here is that the usefulness of both forms is amplified once we realize that it is very easy to transform one into another and back. The following function will split the sequence inside `Hold` into a list of held items:

```
splitHeldSequence[Hold[seq___], f_: Hold] := List @@ Map[f, Hold[seq]]
```

for example,

```
In[274]:= splitHeldSequence[Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 2]]

Out[274]= {Hold[1 + 1], Hold[2 + 2]}
```

grouping them back into a single `Hold` is even easier - just `Apply` `Join`:

```
In[275]:= Join @@ {Hold[1 + 1], Hold[2 + 2]}

Out[275]= Hold[1 + 1, 2 + 2]
```

The two different forms are useful in diferrent circumstances. You can easily use things such as `Union`, `Select`, `Cases` on a list of held items without thinking much about evaluation. Once finished, you can combine them back into a single `Hold`, for example, to feed as unevaluated sequence of arguments to some function.

**EDIT 3**

Per request of @ndroock1, here is a specific example. The setup:

```
l = {1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27} 
S[n_] := Module[{}, l[[n]] = l[[n]] + 1; l] 
Z[n_] := Module[{}, l[[n]] = 0; l]
```

placing functions in `Hold`:

```
In[43]:= held = Hold[Z[1], S[1]]

Out[43]= Hold[Z[1], S[1]]
```

Here is how the `exec` function may look:

```
exec[n_] := MapAt[Evaluate, held, n]
```

Now,

```
In[46]:= {exec[1], exec[2]}

Out[46]= {Hold[{0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27}, S[1]],  Hold[Z[1], {1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27}]}
```

Note that the original variable `held` remains unchanged, since we operate on the copy. Note also that the original setup contains mutable state (`l`), which is not very idiomatic in Mathematica. In particular, the order of evaluations matter:

```
In[61]:= Reverse[{exec[2], exec[1]}]

Out[61]= {Hold[{0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27}, S[1]],  Hold[Z[1], {2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27}]}
```

Whether or not this is desired depends on the specific needs, I just wanted to point this out. Also, while the `exec` above is implemented according to the requested spec, it implicitly depends on a global variable `l`, which I consider a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808).

An alternative way to store functions suggested by @Mr.Wizard can be achieved e.g. like

In[63]:= listOfHeld = splitHeldSequence[held]

Out[63]= {Hold[Z[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808)], Hold[S[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808)]}

and here

```
In[64]:= execAlt[n_] := MapAt[ReleaseHold, listOfHeld, n]

In[70]:= l = {1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27} ;
{execAlt[1], execAlt[2]}

Out[71]= {{{0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27}, Hold[S[1]]}, {Hold[Z[1]], {1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27}}}
```

The same comments about mutability and dependence on a global variable go here as well. This last form is also more suited to query the function type:

```
getType[n_, lh_] := lh[[n]] /. {Hold[_Z] :> zType, Hold[_S] :> sType, _ :> unknownType}
```

for example:

```
In[172]:= getType[#, listOfHeld] & /@ {1, 2}

Out[172]= {zType, sType}
```

Comment: The idea is:

l = {1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9, 27}

S[n_] := Module[{}, l[[n]] = l[[n]] + 1; l]

Z[n_] := Module[{}, l[[n]] = 0; l]

Then I want to store {Z[1],S[1]} in a list, unevaluated.

A function exec[n_]:='Execute function at position n in list'.

I still don't get this to work using Hold.

Comment: @ndroock1  - Please see my edit. If possible, I'd rethink the design, to build from immutable lists.

Comment: Edit 3 does it. Thank you very much. ( I will use it to emulate Cutland's URM ( unlimited register machine ), a concept similar to the Turing Machine. )

Comment: @Leonid. One more thing, the reason for storing and evaluation later is that I want to shuffle the instructions around, and a Jump instruction is required. This means that I want to evaluate the type of function on a position in Held, is it Z,S or other? - I can make a new question if that is your advise.

Comment: @ndroock1 For the case at hand this is easy, see my edit. There is here some potential for a more general question along the lines: "How to determine types of held expressions without evaluating them, based on their heads", but you will have to define what type is, etc. B.t.w., try to avoid starting your functions with capital letters, this may result in a clash with some system symbol.

Answer (score 7):

The first thing that spings to mind is to not use `List` but rather use something like this:

```
 SetAttributes[lst, HoldAll];
 heldL=lst[Plus[1, 1], Times[2, 3]]
```

There will surely be lots of more erudite suggestions though!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `Hold` on every element that you want held:

```
a = {Hold[2 + 2], Hold[2*3]}
```

You can use `HoldForm` on either the elements or the list, if you want the appearance of the list without `Hold` visible:

```
b = {HoldForm[2 + 2], HoldForm[2*3]}

c = HoldForm@{2 + 2, 2*3}
```

```
   {2 + 2, 2 * 3}
```

And you can recover the evaluated form with `ReleaseHold`:

```
a // ReleaseHold
b // ReleaseHold
c // ReleaseHold

Out[8]= {4, 6}

Out[9]= {4, 6}

Out[10]= {4, 6}
```

The form `Hold[2+2, 2*3]` or that of `a` and `b` above are good because you can easily add terms with e.g. `Append`.  For `b` type is it logically:

```
Append[b, HoldForm[8/4]]
```

For `Hold[2+2, 2*3]`:

```
Hold[2+2, 2*3] ~Join~ Hold[8/4]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
lh = Function[u, Hold@u, {HoldAll, Listable}];
k = lh@{2 + 2, Sin[Pi]}
(*
->{Hold[2 + 2], Hold[Sin[\[Pi]]]}
*)
ReleaseHold@First@k
(*
-> 4
*)
```