# PlotLegends` default options

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to redefine an option of the `PlotLegends` package after having loaded it,
but I get for example

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
SetOptions[ListPlot,LegendPosition->{0,0.5}]
=> SetOptions::optnf: LegendPosition is not a known option for ListPlot.
```

I expect such a thing as the options in the `PlotLegends` package aren't built-in to `Plot` and `ListPlot`.

Is there a way to redefine the default options of the `PlotLegends` package?

Comment: The only correct answer here is to **not** use the `PlotLegends` package. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221315/how-do-i-label-different-curves-in-mathematica) question for an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not really in the defaults for `` PlotLegends` ``. To see it, you should inspect the `ListPlot` implementation:

```
In[28]:= Needs["PlotLegends`"]
In[50]:= DownValues[ListPlot]
Out[50]=    
{HoldPattern[ListPlot[PlotLegends`Private`a:PatternSequence[___,
    Except[_?OptionQ]]|PatternSequence[],PlotLegends`Private`opts__?OptionQ]]:>
  PlotLegends`Private`legendListPlot[ListPlot,PlotLegends`Private`a,
    PlotLegend/.Flatten[{PlotLegends`Private`opts}],PlotLegends`Private`opts] 
      /;!FreeQ[Flatten[{PlotLegends`Private`opts}],PlotLegend]}
```

What you see from here is that options must be passed *explicitly* for it to work, and moreover, `PlotLegend` option must be present.

One way to achieve what you want is to use my [option configuration manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192599/create-functions-to-flexibly-define-chart-options-lists-in-mathematica/7197903#7197903), which imitates global options by passing local ones. Here is a version where option-filtering is made optional:

```
ClearAll[setOptionConfiguration, getOptionConfiguration, withOptionConfiguration];
SetAttributes[withOptionConfiguration, HoldFirst];
Module[{optionConfiguration}, optionConfiguration[_][_] = {};
   setOptionConfiguration[f_, tag_, {opts___?OptionQ}, filterQ : (True | False) : True] :=
      optionConfiguration[f][tag] = 
         If[filterQ, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[f]], {opts}];
   getOptionConfiguration[f_, tag_] := optionConfiguration[f][tag];
   withOptionConfiguration[f_[args___], tag_] := 
        f[args, Sequence @@ optionConfiguration[f][tag]];
];
```

To use this, first define your configuration and a short-cut macro, as follows:

```
setOptionConfiguration[ListPlot,"myConfig", {LegendPosition -> {0.8, -0.8}}, False];
withMyConfig =   Function[code, withOptionConfiguration[code, "myConfig"], HoldAll];
```

Now, here you go:

```
withMyConfig[
   ListPlot[{#, Sin[#]} & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.1], PlotLegend -> {"sine"}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Leonid, I always like your bottom-up approach to Mathematica !

Answer (score 0):

`LegendsPosition` works in `ListPlot` without problems (for me at least). You don't happen to have forgotten to load the package by using `Needs["PlotLegends`"]`?

Comment: The problem I have is not about using PlotLegends but about setting default options different than the original ones.

Comment: @Faysal I think it'd be good if you could post what you did to change the default.

Answer (score 0):

@Leonid, I added the possibility to setOptionConfiguration to set default options to f without having to use a short-cut macro.

I use the trick exposed by Alexey Popkov in [What is in your Mathematica tool bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656)

Example:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
setOptionConfiguration[ListPlot, "myConfig", {LegendPosition -> {0.8, -0.8}},SetAsDefault -> True]
ListPlot[{#, Sin[#]} & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, 0.1], PlotLegend -> {"sine"}]
```

Here is the implementation

```
Options[setOptionConfiguration] = {FilterQ -> False, SetAsDefault -> False};

setOptionConfiguration[f_, tag_, {opts___?OptionQ}, OptionsPattern[]] := 
    Module[{protectedFunction}, 

        optionConfiguration[f][tag] = 
            If[OptionValue@FilterQ, FilterRules[{opts}, 
                Options[f]]
                , 
                {opts}
            ];

        If[OptionValue@SetAsDefault, 
            If[(protectedFunction = MemberQ[Attributes[f], Protected]), 
                Unprotect[f];
            ];

            DownValues[f] = 
                Union[
                    {
                        (*I want this new rule to be the first in the DownValues of f*)
                        HoldPattern[f[args___]] :> 
                            Block[{$inF = True}, 
                                withOptionConfiguration[f[args], tag]
                            ] /; ! TrueQ[$inF]
                    }
                    , 
                    DownValues[f]
                ];

            If[protectedFunction, 
                Protect[f];
            ];
        ];
    ];
```

Comment: I see your point, and this is a nice code, but I would not do this in this fashion. The point is that the Gayley - Villegas trick exposed by @Alexey must be used very sparingly. Generally, it is an intrusive operation. If you make routine use of this, your code will be much harder to debug, since you may easily forget for which functions you did the modifications. One of the main points of my option configurator suggestion was that while it "imitates" global option resettings, it is cleaner since it only works within a *lexical* scope of `withOptionConfiguration` or its short-cuts. The ...

Comment: ... function itself is not modified in any way. And, no state is ever changed, since the options are passed locally. This is a sort of a functional imitation of state. Lexically scoped (better yet immutable) code is usually easier to debug because, by avoiding manipulations with the state, it remains compositional. And composition is the key, since it allows you to take some smaller part of the code and debug or modify it in complete isolation from other parts. The Gayley - Villegas trick is a powerful tool, but IMO should be used sparingly and only in cases when nothing else helps.

Comment: By the way, using @Leonid in the answer body does not get me notified - I discovered your newly added answer by chance. It is better to write a comment below the answer of the person you want to notify,  or any other answer on which that person commented, then he/she will be notified for sure.