# Writing vectors to a file without using Export

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am interested in writing multiple vectors to a file such that each vector forms one row in the file, and is written to the file as soon as it is generated. The elements of the vector need to be separated by a single space, and I do not want to include the `{ }` parentheses for the vector. Basically, I want to mimic the `fprintf("file", "%f %f %f\n")` functionality of C.

Here is what I have. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
st1 = OpenWrite["C:\\junk\\mu.out", FormatType -> OutputForm];

vt = Table[
   v = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5];

   For[j = 1, j <= Length[v], j++, 
    WriteString[
     st1, 
     SequenceForm[NumberForm[v[[j]], ExponentFunction -> (Null &)], 
      " "]
     ]
    ];
   Write[st1, ""];
   v,
   {200}
   ];

In[3]:= Close[st1]

Out[3]= "C:\\junk\\mu.out"
```

Based on the wonderful Riffle function, courtesy Arnoud and Mr. Wizard, below, I modified it as follows:

```
WriteVector[stream_, vector_] :=
 Apply[WriteString[stream, ##, "\n"] &, 
  Riffle[Map[NumberForm[#, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)] &, vector], 
   " "]
  ]
```

Comment: how would you define better? faster? using less memory? more elegant? shorter?

Comment: @acl: I guess something more elegant, kind of functional way to do things

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
WriteVector[stream_, vector_] :=
  WriteString[stream, ##, "\n"] & @@ Riffle[vector, " "]
```

and:

```
fname = "c:\\users\\arnoudb\\test.out";
```

then:

```
Do[WriteVector[fname, RandomReal[{0, 1}, 5]],{10}]
```

and check:

```
FilePrint[fname]
```

close stream when done:

```
Close[fname]
```

Comment: I am wondering, is it guaranteed that everything will be written to the file even without calling `Close[stream]` at the end?  (AFAIK in C it is not.)

Comment: @Szabolcs, I don't know. I tend to wrap my code in [`OpenAndRead`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4176381/198315) to eliminate resource leaks.

Comment: @Szabolcs -- WriteString flushes its stream during evaluation.